# Using more than one ESP8266 access point in a network

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I made a board with  ESP8266 as access point. When I turn on one of my board, I can connect to any of them by stations. But when I turn on more than one boards and all of them are in the station's Wi-Fi available range, I can not connect to none of them.

So what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.
The problem is because of the same MAC Address of access points. MAC address of **ESP8266** can be changed by below AT command:

```
AT+CIPAPMAC=<mac address>
```